# Only last fprintf() output is written to the file

Tags: c, append, file-writing

I'm trying to write a program which encrypts a input file and creates an output file after the encryption.

The `fprintf` does work fine if I write to `stdout` but when I send the output to a file, only the last `fprintf` output is written into the file, i.e. if the input file contains 2 lines, the output file contains only the last line encrypted.

Source:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define Max 1024 

int menu() 
{
    printf("To encrypt, input e or E\n");
    printf("To decrypt, input d or D\n");
    printf("To exit, input any other letter\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice and hit return:\n");
    return 0;
}

void encrypto(char*str) 
{

    FILE *ausgabeverschl;
    ausgabeverschl=fopen("encrypted.txt","w");

    int n=0;
    char *p=str ,q[Max];
    while(*p)
    {
        if(islower(*p))
        {
            if((*p>='a')&&(*p<'x'))
                q[n]=toupper(*p + (char)3);
        }
        else
        {
            q[n]=*p+(char)3;
        }
        n++; p++;
    }
    q[n++]='\0';
    fprintf(ausgabeverschl, "%s\n", q);   // problem occurs here
    fclose(ausgabeverschl);
}


void decrypto(char*str) 
{
    FILE *ausgabeunverschl;
    ausgabeunverschl=fopen("decrypted.txt","w");
    int   n=0;
    char *p=str, q[Max];

    while(*p)
    {
        if(isupper(*p))
        {
            if((*p>='D')&&(*p<='Z'))
                q[n]=tolower(*p - (char)3);
        }
        else
        {
            q[n]=*p-(char)3;
        }
        n++; p++;
    }
    q[n++]='\0';
    fprintf(ausgabeunverschl,"%s\n",q);
    fclose(ausgabeunverschl);  
}



int main()
{
    char einlesestring[Max];
    char choice[2];


    FILE    *ein;
        ein=fopen("text.txt","r");


    if(ein!=NULL)
      {
          printf("\nFile found.\n\n");
      }

    if(ein==NULL)
        {
            printf("No file found.\n");
            return 1;
        }


    int counter=0;
    char stringlaenge[Max];

        while (fgets(stringlaenge, Max, ein) != NULL)
            {
                counter++;
            }
  printf(„Counted lines: %d\n", counter);
    rewind(ein);


    menu();
    gets(choice);

    if((choice[0]=='e')||(choice[0]=='E'))
    {
        while(fgets(einlesestring, Max, ein)!= NULL)
        {
            encrypto(einlesestring);
        }
    }
    else if((choice[0]=='d')||(choice[0]=='D'))
    {
        while(fgets(einlesestring,Max, ein)!=NULL)
        {
            decrypto(einlesestring);
        }
    }


    fclose(ein);
    return 0;}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `fopen("encrypted.txt","w")` overwrites any existing file. If you want to append, you have to specify that using `"a"` instead.

Comment: @Wimmel That's not what I was talking about. I don't want to append anything. I'm asking why fprintf() only writes the last line of the encryption and not every line. (with fprintf(stdout,...,..) it works very well.)

Comment: @Wimmel answered that: you open, write and close the file every time the function is called. So the previous file is over written, whereas using `stdout` does not clear the text console, so you still see the previous output.

Comment: @scherzkraperl what is your evidence only the last line is written? Opening the file and looking after the program is finished?. They're *all* being written to the file, and each `fopen` before each write as you have it obliterates the last write before commencing with the next one one. I.e. @Wimmel is right. The final write operation has no follow-up `fopen` using `"w"` mode, so it is the only one that remains

Comment: There is a funny German left quote in one of your `printf`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh thank you! Now it's clear :-) (and sorry Wimmel i didn't understand your comment in this short way) Would there be a possibility to open the file inside the "main", just in case I need it some day?

Comment: @JensGustedt yes ;-) reason: I'm from Austria

Comment: You can open the file in the main and pass the file pointer to the function, modified as `void encrypto(char*str, FILE *ausgabeverschl)`